# How to debug or/and trace the execution flow in C# with event handlers in it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, trace

I'm having a problem in tracing the execution flow in my c# code.With f10 or f11 i am able to trace just till the end of the main method.But in the runtime when an event is generated the function being executed is not traced. But I want to trace the code that is getting executed after the event is generated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a breakpoint on the left side of your code  like
[image]

and run your project by hitting (F5)  .
And you can trace your code using F10(Step Over) and F11(Step Into) !
For more information , use this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) link !

Comment: Thank you...this helped me in identifying my problem